# Change width of points in geom_pointrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, resize

I'm just starting to learn ggplot2 and got stuck trying to change the width of the points using geom_pointrange

My data:

```
   Pop    Beta         SE Size        lo        hi name
2 std1 -1.9590 0.30000000  601 -2.259000 -1.659000 std1
1 std2 -2.2170 0.17480000 1532 -2.391800 -2.042200 std2
3 std3 -2.3180 0.17160000 1763 -2.489600 -2.146400 std3
4 std4 -2.0940 0.18700000 1176 -2.281000 -1.907000 std4
5 std6 -1.5080 0.19670000 1136 -1.704700 -1.311300 std6
6 meta -2.0561 0.08695935 6208 -2.143059 -1.969141 meta
```

The plot:

```
p <- ggplot()+
  geom_pointrange(data=data, aes(x=name, y=Beta, ymin=lo, ymax=hi), shape=c(rep(22,5),23), lwd=0.3,
                  fill=c(rep("white",5),"white"), color = c(rep("#525252",5),"red"), 
                  fatten = c((data$Size/200)[c(1:5)],5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2)+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab('') + theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
                      ylab("") + ggtitle(paste(trait,i,sep=" "))
plot(p)
```

My problem is that I want the whiskers to be really thin **as well** as the points, but when I change the `lwd` parameter only the whiskers width change. I tried using `width` but got an error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: width
```

[image]

**EDIT with plot:**
I want the width of my boxed to be the same width as the whiskers

Comment: Use combination of `size` and `fatten` to change the overal / relative sizes of the pointranges. Or perhaps you are looking for `stroke`? I'm a bit unsure what the issue is (adding a plot may help).

Comment: I believe instead of `lwd` the syntax should be `width`

Comment: @Axeman See edit post.... I tried `stroke` and it solved my problem! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although undocumented, `geom_pointrange` takes the same arguments for the central point that `geom_point` does. And at the examples of `?geom_point` we can read:

```
# For shapes that have a border (like 21), you can colour the inside and
# outside separately. Use the stroke aesthetic to modify the width of the
# border
```

Comment: any idea of how I can avoid seeing whiskers through the points, even when fill is specified to be "white" like in the example above? Thanks